# Stub a CSV file in Ruby Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, csv, testunit

So I have a Ruby script which parses a CSV file as a list of rules and does some processing and returns an array of hashes as processed data.

CSV looks like this:

```
id_number,rule,notes
1,"dummy_rule","necessary"
2,"sample_rule","optional"
```

The parsing of CSV looks like this:

```
def parse_csv(file_name)
  filtered_data = []
  CSV.foreach(file_name, headers: true) do |row|
    filtered_data << row # some processing
  end
  filtered_data
end
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to stub/mock an actual CSV file for unit testing in such a way that I could pass a "filename" into this function. I could make a CSV object and use the generate function but then the actual filename would not be possible.

```
def test_parse_csv
   expected_result = ["id_number"=>1, "rule"=>"dummy_rule", "notes"=>"optional"}]
   # stub/mock csv with filename: say "rules.csv"
   assert.equal(expected_result, parse_csv(file_name))
end
```

I use Test::Ruby

I also found a ruby gem library called mocha but I don't know how this works for CSVs

https://github.com/freerange/mocha

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a support directory inside your test directory then create a file..

```
# test/support/rules.csv
id_number,rule,notes
1,"dummy_rule","necessary"
2,"sample_rule","optional"
```

Your test should look like this, also adding an opening curly bracket which looks like you've missed on line #2.

```
def test_parse_csv
   expected_result = [{"id_number"=>1, "rule"=>"dummy_rule", "notes"=>"optional"}]
   assert.equal(expected_result, parse_csv(File.read(csv_file)).first)
end

def csv_file
  Rails.root.join('test', 'support', 'rules.csv') 
end
```

**EDIT**: Sorry, I should have noticed this wasn't Ruby on Rails... heres a ruby solution:

```
def test_parse_csv
   expected_result = [{"id_number"=>1, "rule"=>"dummy_rule", "notes"=>"optional"}]
   assert.equal(expected_result, parse_csv(csv_file).first)
end

def csv_file
  File.read('test/support/rules.csv') 
end
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid making a physical csv file as test data. And I don't use Rails, only Ruby.

Comment: That's my fault, should have seen. A ruby solution has been added. I don't think you have much choice but to create a csv file I'm afraid, you can stub the result of `#parse_csv`, but you'll be skipping over testing this specific functionality.

Comment: It is also worth adding, that there isn't anything wrong with adding a physical csv file as part of your test suite. It's perfectly acceptable and a thorough way of testing your core functionality.

Comment: Yup. I know that approach and there's nothing wrong about it. I just want to know if what I asked is possible.

Comment: Of course, a valid question :) I would answer that it's not possible, also (OOP) best practice would suggest not too, this answer here is great in explaining why and it could be applicable to you if you wish to follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/11692821/1235816

Comment: Chose this as answer due to very detailed answer and for giving additional reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my test `let(:raw_csv) { "row_number \n 1 \n 2" }`, telling myself that a CSV file was surely read as a simple string with linebreaks and commas... and it works fine. Be careful with additional whitespaces and commas, it is easy to make a mistake.